# how do i get the fields selected in the gridview

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, webforms

So basically i want to create a booking and a booking can have multiple orders but i dont know how to store the orders that have been selected in the other pages etc. but I already know i have to do a cycle to run the gridview bue i dont know how to do that with a pager and with a search textbox.

this is how it looks:
[image]

Current CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Gestão_de_embarques
{
    public partial class CriarEcomenda : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constring"].ConnectionString);
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            string user = Convert.ToString(Session["user"]);

            username.Text = user;

            if (Session["user"] == null || Session["login"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx", false);
            }

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                refreshdata();
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        public void refreshdata()
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT No_ from [Encomenda]", con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();

            if (txtSearch.Value == "")
            {
                refreshdata();
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT No_ from [encomenda] where No_= @No_", con);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@No_", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtSearch.Value;

                    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    if (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        sdr.Close();
                        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();

                        con.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        sdr.Close();
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                        ButtonCreate.Visible = false;
                        
                    }
                }

                    
                catch(Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
        }

        protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            refreshdata();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Loop through all GridViewRows in your GridView.  While in each row, use FindControl() and cast to the object (Checkbox or Textbox) to then grab the ````Checked```` or ````Text```` property depending on what object you are finding.

Comment: can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you were not data paging, then the un-bound check box would persist and survive even post backs.

But, since you have data paging? Then you persist the selected PK id from the database. (you don't have to display the pk row, but just set DataKeys = "ID" or what ever your PK row is from the database.

As noted, with searching and paging, you have to re-bind the grid, so you can't use the grid to persist the selected check boxes. Say we have a list of hotels to select.

Our markup would be this:

```
   <div style="width:40%">
      <asp:GridView ID="MyGrid" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover" 
          DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="MyGrid_RowDataBound" >

        <Columns>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="Hotel Name" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="Hotel Name" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Province" HeaderText="Province" />

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show Selected rows" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <br />
        <br />

    </div>
```

And code to load up this grid would be:

```
    List<int> MySelected = new List<int>();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            LoadGrid();
            ViewState["MySelected"] = MySelected;
        }
        else
        {
            MySelected = (List<int>)ViewState["MySelected"];
        }
    }

    public void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName",
            new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST3)))
        {

            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            DataTable rst = new DataTable();
            rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            MyGrid.DataSource = rst;
            MyGrid.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void MyGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            int PkRow = (int)((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["ID"];
            CheckBox ckbox = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
            if (MySelected.Contains(PkRow)) {
                ckbox.Checked = true;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox ckBox = (CheckBox)sender;
        GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)ckBox.Parent.Parent;

        int RowPK = (int)(MyGrid.DataKeys[gvRow.RowIndex]["ID"]);
        if (ckBox.Checked)
            MySelected.Add(RowPK);
        else
            MySelected.Remove(RowPK);
    }
```

Now how I just created a simple list. When you check a box, you simply add the PK row from the GridRow "PK" to the list.

The code to get/work the "list" from the database thus will look like this:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MyPkList = string.Join(",", MySelected);
        string strSQL = "SELECT * from tblHotels where ID IN(" + MyPkList + ")";

        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST3)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            DataTable rstPickList = new DataTable();
            rstPickList.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());

            foreach (DataRow OneRow in rstPickList.Rows)
            {
                Response.Write("<h2> PK = " + OneRow["Id"].ToString() + " Hotel Name = " + OneRow["HotelName"] + "</h2>");

            }
        }
    }
```

So, if I check say 3 rows, and hit that button, you get this:

[image]

this does mean that you have to set the check box to auto post back. And that thus means for a check box click, you do post-back. However, you could drop the whole grid in a update panel if you need to only post back that grid selecting part and not the whole page.

Once you have that list of PK values from the database, then as the button shows, we have to process against the database table, and we can't use the grid due to paging. As noted, if the gridview could fit on one page, then you would not need the persisting code, and you could just loop the grid view to get the checked rows - you would not need ANY code to persist the values.

Comment: but if i dont use the pager the gridview will be giant and my table doesnt have a PK field either

Comment: Can i do the same validation just using the Number of my order?

Comment: Yes - saving the PK in that list, you save that number, and then use that for the  checked box or not routine. So in place of PK, you have that grid row - if that column is a datafield, then you use cells to get the value. If it is a templated field, then you use find control. So, in place of PK in that list, store the order number. The routines will be near identical to what tIn fact if you make that change then the code don't need to be changed. I pulling from the DataKhey are now. And if you want, simple set DataKeys = "ordernum" or whatever it is. (so replace ID with your column)

Comment: i replaced ID for my column but now the cs code is set for an int value and not for a nvarchar and i cant solve that

Comment: But you changed your "list" or collection that holds these values from int to string, right? You don't have to use DataKeys - they tend to be "more" handy for columns that you don't have or don't dispay in the grid. But sure, change MySelected from "int" to string, and you should be fine. And you don't have to use data keys here. In all of that code and I am betting MOST of YOUR code you will OFTEN pull/use/grab data from the one grid row in all of those events. I mean, look very close - the way I pull out the check box value is ALSO the SAME way you can pull other values from that row

Comment: So your list (MySelection) can be any data type you want. If you change your collection (or list in this case)  to a string, then you can freely use DataKeys collection, but you certainly don't have to use DataKeys. But what kind of data type do you want for your final "list" of things selected. You can make a list of any data type here.  Change your "list" type to store strings - not <int> like we have.